# "Кушать" и "есть". Оттенки значений

Tags: лексика, стилистика, глаголы

Я как-то столкнулся с таким спором по поводу глаголов ***кушать*** и ***есть***.
Если коротко, то были высказаны следующие мнения:

1. Эти слова совершенно равнозначны.
2. "Кушать" — слово детское, а по-взрослому надо говорить "есть".
3. "Кушать" — это как-то по-старинному, вроде "извольте откушать".

А как думают участники этого форума?
Есть ли какие-то оттенки значений, отличающие эти слова?

Comment: Спасибо за хорошие ответы!

Comment: См. также https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/40857/%d0%9a%d1%83%d1%88%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%82%d1%8c (Кушать или есть?)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Нашла на "Грамоте".
Вопрос
**Как правильно: есть или кушать?**

Глаголы есть и кушать — синонимы. Как синонимы они выступают с значением «принимать пищу, употреблять в пищу». Эти слова относятся к так называемым стилистическим синонимам. **Есть и кушать различаются стилистически**, их употребление (прежде всего глагола кушать) регулируется определенными ситуациями речевого общения.
**Глагол "есть"** употребляется в литературной речи (в том числе и в современной) **несравненно шире своего синонима**. Во-первых, есть — основное слово, семантическая доминанта в синонимическом ряду, обозначающем процесс еды: есть — вкушать — питаться — насыщаться — кушать — уплетать — лопать — жрать — шамать — штефкать (видимо, этот ряд можно продолжить). Во-вторых, есть — нейтральное в экспрессивном отношении слово, общеупотребительное.
Глагол же **"кушать"** стилистически ограничен в своем употреблении прежде всего как слово, относящееся к речевому этикету; **вежливое приглашение гостя**, гостей к столу. В этой ситуации используют инфинитив (кушать) — в составе этикетной формулы «кушать подано, прошу к столу» или в повелительном наклонении — в составе другой формулы «кушайте, пожалуйста!».
Затем кушать (равно как и глаголы покушать, скушать) может употребляться **в обращении к детям:** Ты кушал (покушал)? Хочешь кушать (покушать)? Скушай вот это. Покушай (скушай) что-нибудь и т. п. **Так же принято обращаться и к женщинам** (разумеется, на «вы» или на «ты» в зависимости от обстоятельств и ситуации общения). С аналогичными вопросами и советами (кроме ситуации приглашения к столу или начать трапезу). К мужчинам так обычно не обращаются. В таких ситуациях "кушать" заменяют на "есть".
**Употребление кушать в 1 лице единственного числа настоящего времени (я кушаю) или в прошедшем времени (я кушал) допустимо только в речи детей и женщин.**
Использование глагола кушать в речи мужчин о себе (хочу кушать, я кушаю, я (не) кушал), а также когда мужчина или женщина говорит от имени четы или семьи: мы (уже) кушали (покушали), мы (не) хотим кушать и т. п., противоречит стилистической норме современного литературного языка, придаёт речи манерность, некоторую слащавость, квалифицируется как проявление мещанства в речи.

Comment: При всем уважении к "Справке" никак не могу согласиться с гендерным шовинизмом. ;)  
"Кушать", обращенное ко взрослым, что мужчинам, что женщинам, или сказанное взрослыми о себе воспринимается одинаково плохо. Или - в отдельных ситуациях - одинаково допустимо. 

С другой стороны, в ответе не охвачен ряд ситуацций. Скажем, "Ну что, кушать будем?" - никакой манерщиной не отдает.

Answer (score 7):

Слова семантически близки, но стилистически не совсем равнозначны. 
Об истории не буду, ближе к 1917 г. сложилось разделение, что кушают благородные, ну и там посетители кабаков и рестораций, едят же все остальные, включая братьев наших меньших. Революция упразднила эти различия, "кушать" стало восприниматься как нечто слащаво-манерное или, как правильно замечено, к детям обращенное. В общем-то я не вижу причин возмущаться. Пусть оно так будет.

Кроме того у "кушать" более широкий круг значений. Водку тоже, простите, кушают. Но никак не едят. И это отнюдь не современное словотворчество, а следы довольно древних оборотов.

Comment: *Водку тоже, простите, кушают.* Да, но её и пьют тоже.

Comment: @АртёмЛуговой *Да, но её и пьют тоже* - Ну с этим-то никто не спорит. Мы же о "кушать" и стилистике его значений.

Comment: Да я так, на всякий случай отметил, вдруг кто-то подумает, что "кушать водку" правильно, а пить — нет.

Answer (score 4):

> ... допустимо только в речи детей и женщин
>
> противоречит стилистической норме современного литературного языка

Не могу согласиться. Слово "кушать" активно употребляется и в отношении взрослых, в том числе мужчин.
Стилистически различие мне видится в некоторой интимности, семейности "кушать" по сравнению с "есть". В вопросе жены мужу "Ты покушал?" нет никакого мещанства, а слышится только оттенок нежности и заботы по сравнению с деловым "Ты поел?".

Comment: Очень субъективно. Большинство все-таки видит слащавость.

Comment: Вы проводили какие-то исследования, чтобы утверждать по поводу большинства?

Comment: Нет, сичтаю этот факт общеизвестным.  
А вы проводили какие-то исследования в отношении "активно употребляется"?!

Comment: Я пишу о своих личных субъективных ощущениях, для этого исследования не нужны.

Comment: А почему с других требуете? Я, может, тоже о своих личных.

Comment: Захотелось покушать пельмешков по-мещански знаете ли, с перчиком да уксусом... Развели тут, понимаешь, темы!

Comment: Раз уж пишем о личных ощущениях, то вставлю свои пять копеек: на Урале и в Югре "кушают" часто и в слащавости друг друга не обвиняют.

Answer (score 2):

Родилась и живу в Петербурге, с детства "кушать" не использовалось в речи - ни в детском саду, ни в школе, ни потом в университете... Значение слова известно и понятно, активно слышно по литературе, в основном все-таки не современной...

И в реальной жизни "кушает" только подруга из Хабаровска... Что немножко режет слух...

Других исследований не проводила, возможно, у кого-то иной опыт.

Answer (score 1):

Если я говорю "кушать" там, где кто-то ожидает услышать "есть" и воспринимает это как что-то слащавое, — это не мои проблемы. Для меня разница между этими двумя словами предельно сглажена, и никакой слащавости, детскости, женственности, интима или что вы там себе нафантазируете, я не вкладываю. Слова "кушать" и "есть" обычно употребляются в неформальной обстановке, чаще дома, для формальной ситуации есть "питаться". Вне дома — "есть хочу", "кушать хочу", "жрать хочу", "пойдем в кафешку".

Comment: Ну, видите ли,мы здесь говорим как раз об общих и объективных проблемах, а не Вашем личном отношении.  "Питаться" же не является полным синонимом "кушать" и "есть", Дело не в формальности обстановки, а в значениях. Питаться - это ближе к "поедать":  a) как правило требует "чем" и б) в отношении большой группы коллектива. Индивидуум же "питается" только в переносном смысле. Надеждами, например. Да и не только это.

Answer (score 0):

В журнале «Филологический маньяк» есть статья «Почему нельзя употреблять глагол «КУШАТЬ» вместо «ЕСТЬ?» говориться об особых условиях, когда допускается говорить «кушать», а именно:
1.  При вежливой форме приглашения к еде
2.  В инфинитивной форме (но, извините, это тоже приглашение) «кушать подано, прошу к столу».
3.  когда разговор ведется с детьми: «Ты кушал?», «Хочешь покушать?» (но, извините, это тоже приглашение, ибо родитель приготовил/купил еду для ребёнка)
Далее «но взрослый человек о себе или любой человек, говорящий от имени группы людей («я кушаю», «мы хотим кушать»), не должны использовать это слово в подобной формулировке. Только «я ем», «мы хотим есть» и т.п. 
•
 А вот такая деталь, которая поможет понять истоки некоторых "особых условий" в употреблении глагола "кушать" сегодня.
Возможно, что я заблуждаюсь, но тем не менее рискну изложить свою мысль. 
В литературе 19 века можно найти такие сценки, когда хозяин, или хозяйка, или же повар как автор ( хозяин) приготовленного блюда, приглашают гостей к столу, отпробовать явства. (Если это делали слуги, они лишь исполняли волю хозяев). При этом за столом произносилась фраза " откушайте нашего того-то", как в отношении блюд, которые поедались через прожёвывание, так и - напитков. " откушайте нашей наливочки". Это наводит на мысль, что первоначально глагол " кушать/ откушать означал не " ешьте", а "попробуйте", и именно при таком понимании предлагаемый объект мог бы быть и жидким. У меня в голове вырисовывается предположение, что слово " кушать/откушать" пришло в русский язык, например, из немецкого языка:"auskosten (аускостен)"- попробовать. В некоторых диалектах это слово произносилось как "аускоштен-коштен"- отсюда и русифицированное «кош/куш», "кушать". 
Именно потому что форма "кушайте-откушайте" употреблялась в функции " пригласить неких-других к столу, чтобы отпробовать угощение, сегодня, когда человек сам про себя говорит "я хочу кушать/ я кушаю", это сочетание из-за скрытого отголоска прошлых значений кажется несуразным, неправильным, режет слух, ибо не может человек сам себя приглашать к столу отпробовать еду (тем более ту, которую он сам приготовил/купил). 
Вот как-то так. Конечно, надо бы посмотреть, когда в русском языке появилось само слово  "попробовать", которое, кажется, вытеснило слово " (от)кушайте" со своего места, и оно, оказавшись как бы неудел, стало «мешаться под ногами» у  глагола «есть/принимать пищу», что и послужило причиной нарушений в языковом восприятии молодого поколения с неустоявшейся, шаткой языковой базой. Не случайно, ведь, старшее поколение более чувствительно к этим ошибкам.
Из статьи: «Еще Чуковский отмечал, что его коробит нескромное, заносчивое выражение «я кушаю». Человек, употребляющий такую форму по отношению к себе, как передает один из словарей, «выглядит немного смешно – у него отсутствует либо чувство языка, либо чувство юмора». 
Такая форма не соотносится с нормами современного русского языка, манерна, считается проявлением мещанства». 
В заключении добавлю, что корень «KOS-» (GUS-) немецкого слова «auskosten»/(попробовать)  исходит из латинского слова «De GUStibus non disputatur» - О вкусах не спорят.  Примерно так: GUStibus-/ausKOSten-/КУШать-
Библиографический список
•   Крылов Г.А. «Словарь ошибок русского языка», 2006 г.
•   Чуковский К. «Живой как жизнь », 1962 г.