# Есть и есть (кушать)

Tags: омонимы

Скажите, пожалуйста, а вот слова "есть" и "есть" (в значении "кушать") просто омонимы или же у них общее происхождение?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Тут](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/8968/%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%BA%D1%83%D1%88%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B8-%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9) и [Тут](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/8968/%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%BA%D1%83%D1%88%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B8-%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9)

В двух словах. Это совершенно разные по происхождению слова. Есть (еду) писалось через ять (в другой ступени чередования этот ять перешел в я). Это исключает всякое родство. Фонетическое же сходство объясняется тем, что от древних корней неизменными по сути отсалось только по одной букве (два звука), звучание которых сбилзилось и совпало и конечном счете. Остальное - общего происхождения, но это суффиксы.

Comment: Не поторопились ли? По ссылке вопрос о различии между есть и кушать, а в вопросе про слово кушать ничего не говорится, вопрос о другом.

Comment: Есть в значении кушать ранее имело форму 'ясти', ср. яства.

Comment: Без проблем. Переоткрою.  
Но вообще-то я точно помню, что отвечал уже даже на узкий вопрос об этимологии того и другого "есть".

Точно, нашел. По второй ссылке.