# Немного о глаголе "есть"

Tags: лингвистика

У меня сразу несколько вопросов о нем.
Во-первых, всегда интересовало: "есть" (в значении "имеется") и "есть" (в значении "кушать") - это омонимы или они как-то связаны?
И второе. Понимаю, что вопрос глупый из серии "почему так", но все же интересно. Почему у глагол "есть" звучит таким образом только в настоящем времени, а в других он уже "был" и "будет"?

Comment: Про кушать и есть: http://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/13142/%D0%95%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B8-%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BA%D1%83%D1%88%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C

Comment: То, что есть, никогда не было и не будет. Оно не есть потому что... Оно есть потому что есть. ЕСТЬ - Великое Слово

Answer (score 1):

> > это омонимы или они как-то связаны?

Вряд ли, потому что в древнерусском "ясти" – есть. Однокоренные – еда, снедь и даже яд. Корень "е" ("я"). Похоже, там раньше писался ять. Лень проверять. )))

Answer (score 0):

Изначально два разных слова. ***Есть*** как ***быть***, являться, существовать и ***ясть*** (впереди — Юс малый, по звуку среднее между *И* и *Я*, ) как ***есть*** — от др.-русс. *ясть*, *яства*. На письме неотличимыми их сделали благодарные потомки.

По второму вопросу: ***быть*** можно воспринимать как *бытовать*, и всё встанет на свои места.

Answer (score 0):

Они омонимы, потому что ять(ѣ) в русском языке стал произноситься как "е", а с 1918 года и писаться как "е".

Раньше было:

**есть** (настоящее время глагола **быть**)

**ѣсть** - синоним **кушать**

ѣ - еще в 18 веке поизносилась не как "е". У ѣ было свое произношение. Затем это произношение сравнялось с "е".