# Кушать или есть?

Tags: синонимы, глаголы, просторечия

Процентов девяносто россиян говорят:
*я ещё не **кушал**;

ты хочешь **кушать**?

пойдём **покушаем**.*
И т.д. и т.п.

Я что-то пропустил и такое употребление глагола "кушать" стало нормативным?
Можно ли объяснить невостребованность глагола "есть"?

Comment: См. также https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/8968/%d0%9a%d1%83%d1%88%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b8-%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%9e%d1%82%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%ba%d0%b8-%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b9 (“Кушать” и “есть”. Оттенки значений)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Здесь](http://www.gramota.ru/spravka/trudnosti/36_143) об этом рассказано подробно и доступно.

Цитата:

"Глагол **есть** употребляется в литературной речи (в том числе и в современной) несравненно шире своего синонима...

Глагол же **кушать** стилистически ограничен в своем употреблении прежде всего как слово, относящееся к речевому этикету; вежливое приглашение гостя, гостей к столу. В этой ситуации используют инфинитив (кушать) — в составе этикетной формулы «кушать подано, прошу к столу» или в повелительном наклонении — в составе другой формулы «кушайте, пожалуйста!».

Затем **кушать** (равно как и глаголы покушать, скушать) может употребляться в обращении к детям: Ты кушал (покушал)? Хочешь кушать (покушать)? Скушай вот это. Покушай (скушай) что-нибудь и т. п. Так же принято обращаться и к женщинам (разумеется, на «вы» или на «ты» в зависимости от обстоятельств и ситуации общения). С аналогичными вопросами и советами (кроме ситуации приглашения к столу или начать трапезу). К мужчинам так обычно не обращаются. В таких ситуациях кушать заменяют на есть.

Употребление **кушать** в 1-м лице единственного числа настоящего времени (я кушаю) или в прошедшем времени (я кушал) допустимо только в речи детей и женщин.
Использование глагола кушать в речи мужчин о себе (хочу кушать, я кушаю, я (не) кушал), а также когда мужчина или женщина говорит от имени четы или семьи: мы (уже) кушали (покушали), мы (не) хотим кушать и т. п., противоречит стилистической норме современного литературного языка, придаёт речи манерность, некоторую слащавость, квалифицируется как проявление мещанства в речи".

Comment: Об употреблении слова "кушать" при в обращении к детям и гостям я знаю. А вот то, что женщины в цитируемой Вами рекомендации приравниваются к детям, несколько смущает.)

С  п  а  с  и  б  о!

Comment: Честно говоря, и я удивилась, прочитав о женщинах.

Answer (score 4):

Кушать - это не есть, а пробовать пищу. Поэтому мы и приглашаем гостей кушать, то есть попробовать угощение. Господа раньше также только кушали, а не ели. Отсюда манерность и слащавость, которая усматривается в остальных ситуациях при  употреблении этого слова. Исключение делается только для обращения к детям.

В то же время нарушение этой нормы отнюдь не редкость, и интересно было бы собрать статистику по регионам. Иногда вполне грамотные люди употребляют это слово, считая его полным  синонимом глагола "есть".

Это, конечно, огорчает. Наверное, в этих случаях нужно не только обозначать норму речи, но и объяснять ее. Возможно, тогда бы они предпочли есть свой обед, а не пробовать его.

Comment: Нарушение этой нормы далеко не редкость. Большинство знакомых мне людей с высшим образованием, которым чуть больше или чуть меньше сорока лет, только глагол "кушать" и употребляют. Нескольких из них я
приучил говорить слово "есть", но это капля в море.

Благодарю!

Comment: Учитывая то, что так говорит большое количество людей, среди которых много и вполне грамотных, стоит поднять вопрос, а кем именно эта самая слащавость усматривается? Возможно, она уже выветрилась? Что касается «кушать — это не есть, а пробовать», то Вы, наверное, лучше меня знаете, что значения слов меняются: сужаются, расширяются, сдвигаются.

Answer (score 1):

Да, КУШАЮТ дети, а взрослые  -  ЕДЯТ.

Comment: Все едят. И дети. Есть - слово основное, монументальное. Наряду с ПИТЬ. Еда и Питие. Кушать - синоним, пришедший со стороны приземлённых КУСАТЬ, ЗАКУСИТЬ, ПЕРЕКУСЫВАТЬ, КУСОК, поэтому синоним условный. Можно ли им заменить ЕСТЬ в известном: грех - не есть необходимое? Только у кровати капризного больного.

Answer (score 0):

Насколько я помню, нас в школе учили глагол "есть" употреблять применительно к себе, когда человек хочет сказать, что он сам употреблял пищу: "я уже поел, я хочу есть". Когда же мы говорим о других людях, в том числе и приглашаем к столу, принято употреблять "кушать": "кушать подано, Вы будете кушать".