# Корректны ли утверждения о невозможности употребления слова "кушать" в нейтральном контексте? Примеры из классики опровергают это

Tags: лексика, стилистика, выбор-слов

*Он хорошо говорит, — заметила генеральша, обращаясь к дочерям и продолжая кивать головой вслед за каждым словом князя, — я даже не ожидала. Стало быть, всё пустяки и неправда; по обыкновению. Кушайте, князь, и рассказывайте: где вы родились, где воспитывались? Я хочу всё знать; вы чрезвычайно меня интересуете.
Князь поблагодарил и, кушая с большим аппетитом, стал снова передавать всё то, о чем ему уже неоднократно приходилось говорить в это утро. Генеральша становилась всё довольнее и довольнее* (Ф. М. Достоевский. Идиот).

*А вместо всего этого, вот он, богатый муж неверной жены, камергер в отставке, любящий покушать, выпить и расстегнувшись побранить легко правительство, член Московского Английского клуба и всеми любимый член московского общества. Он долго не мог помириться
с той мыслью, что он есть тот самый отставной московский камергер, тип которого он так глубоко презирал семь лет тому назад* (Л. Толстой. Война и мир).

*Арина Власьевна была настоящая русская дворяночка прежнего времени... об устрицах говорила не иначе, как с содроганием; любила покушать – и строго постилась; спала десять часов в сутки – и не ложилась вовсе, если у Василия Ивановича заболевала голова...* (И. С. Тургенев. Отцы и дети)

*Дом вытянулся в длину, в один этаж, с мезонином. Во всем благословенное обилие: гость приедет — как Одиссей в гости к царю.
Многочисленное семейство то и дело сидит за столом, а в семействе человек восемнадцать: то чай кушают, то кофе кушают, то просто кушают. Кушают в столовой, кушают в беседке, кушают на лужку, кушают на балконе* (И. Гончаров. Обрыв).

*Изливши свои чувства и успокоившись, граф налил мне стакан холодного красно-бурого чая и придвинул к моим рукам ящик с печеньями.

— Кушай… Проездом через Москву у Эйнема купил* (А. П. Чехов. Драма на охоте).

*В описываемое мною время Московский трактир после трех часов пополудни решительно представлял как бы продолжение заседаний ближайших присутственных мест. За отдельными столиками обыкновенно сидели, кушали и пили разные, до шестого класса включительно, служебные лица вместе с своими просителями, кои угощали их обильно и радушно* (А. Писемский. Масоны).

*– А все это отчего? – сказал, кушая арбуз, Горданов, – все это оттого, что давят человека вдосталь, как прессом жмут, и средств поправиться уже никаких не оставляют.

...

Оркестр играл превосходно: иллюминация задалась, как нельзя лучше; фонтан шумел, публика гуляла, пила, кушала* (Н. Лесков. На ножах).

**XX век:**

*Она вздохнула и, закрыв глаза, откинула голову на отвал дивана. Я подумал, глядя на ее бескровные, сиреневые губы, что она, верно, голодна, подал ей чашку чаю и тарелку с булкой, сел на диван тронул ее за руку:

— Кушайте, пожалуйста.

Она открыла глаза и молча стала пить и есть* (И. Бунин. Три рубля).

*Характерно, что убийца после совершения преступления пил вино и кушал бисквиты — остатки того и другого были найдены на столе со следами окровавленных пальцев* (Л. Андреев. Иван Иванович).

Царь Голод (обращается к Зрителям очень веселым и открытым голосом). *А теперь, милостивые государи, я предложил бы сделать перерыв и покушать. Правосудие — вещь утомительная, и нужно подкрепить силы. (Галантно.)  Особенно прекрасным дамам и девицам. Прошу!

Радостные возгласы.  Кушать! Кушать!*
...
*Судьи стаскивают парики, открывая лысые головы, и постепенно вмешиваются в толпу, пожимают руки и искоса, с притворным равнодушием, поглядывают на кушающих.

Смерть вынула из кармана сухой бутерброд с сыром и кушает в одиночестве* (Л. Н. Андреев. Царь Голод).

*Под нею сидел черношляпый бродяга, запивая местной родниковой водицей сухую горбушку странника, прохлаждаясь от пыльных российских верст; под ней сидел, на ней и вырезал ножичком по сочной мякоти коры: «Клокачев Андрей. Долой насилье!» Покушав, ушел, а след остался…

Целый вечер Заварихин просидел задумчивый, крошки не скушал, шохал изредка корочку да вздыхал под-спудно, ровно кипы ворочал, — словом, вел себя, как ему и полагалось по характеру проглоченной наживки* (Л. Леонов. Вор).

*Против него твердо поместился, разложив локти по столу, пожилой, лысоватый человек, с большим лицом и очень сильными очками на мягком носу, одетый в серый пиджак, в цветной рубашке «фантазия», с черным шнурком вместо галстука. Он сосредоточенно кушал и молчал. Варавка, назвав длинную двойную фамилию, прибавил:

– Наш редактор.*
*…Кушал он очень интересно и с великой осторожностью. Внимательно следил, чтоб куски холодного мяса и ветчины были равномерны, тщательно обрезывал ножом излишек их, пронзал вилкой оба куска и, прежде чем положить их в рот, на широкие, тупые зубы, поднимал вилку на уровень очков, испытующе осматривал двуцветные кусочки. Даже огурец он кушал с великой осторожностью, как рыбу, точно ожидая встретить в огурце кость* (М. Горький. Клим Самгин).

*Я дошел до того, что придумал себе резь в желудке, и Ирена запретила мне кушать, черт меня подери, грубую пищу и несколько раз приносила из дома сметанковые сырники, упрятанные в целлофановый мешок и обернутые газетами, чтобы не остыли* (Константин Воробьев. Вот пришел великан).

*Подходило время ей так и так уезжать, и из хозяйственной сумки она стала вынимать и показывать мужу, что привезла ему кушать. Рукава её шубы так уширены были манжетами из чернобурки, что едва входили в раззявленную пасть сумки* (А. Солженицын. Раковый корпус).

Что вызывает недоумение — повтор из комментария в комментарий: это слово употребляли только лакеи. Предоставленный материал убедительно опровергает это мнение: так говорили и аристократы, и интеллигенты, и мужчины, и женщины. Причем границы активного употребления этого слова выходят далеко за рамки 19 века.
Как показывают приведенные примеры из русской классики, "кушать" в речи автора встречается не менее часто, чем в речи персонажей. А это — главный показатель литературности слова, того, что оно используется не только и не столько как характерологическое средство, отражающее особенности и уровень культурно-речевого развития персонажа, но и как средство коммуникации между автором и читателем. Классики не боятся упреков в слащавости, необразованности и дурном вкусе.

Comment: См.. также https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/40857/%d0%9a%d1%83%d1%88%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%82%d1%8c

Comment: По-моему, это комментарий к вопросу https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/8968/%d0%9a%d1%83%d1%88%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b8-%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%9e%d1%82%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%ba%d0%b8-%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b9 (“Кушать” и “есть”. Оттенки значений), и там ему место.

Comment: Я не считаю, что на мой вопрос ответили.  На вашем сайте и других специализированных сайтах по русскому языку сайтах есть, к сожалению, очевидная тенденция игнорирования реального литературного материала.  Утверждения экспертов о недопустимости употребления слова "кушать" в речи мужчин, в нейтральных контекстах, о слащавости и мещанском характере данного слова, подаваемые как истина в последней инстанции, явно бездоказательны. Надо более серьезно аргумент ировать свою позицию, опираясь на факты авторитетного словоупотребления. В этом смысл моего вопроса (и ответа).

Comment: Конечно, может быть, установка на набирание "репутаций" представляет собой удачный маркетинговый ход. Но количество не переходит автоматически в качество. Есть смысл подумать о повышении требований к обоснованности "экспертных заключений", предлагаемых в качестве авторитетных ответов на вопросы.

Comment: @БорисБобылев в таком виде вопрос возможен, поэтому переоткрыл ваш вопрос.

Comment: Вынужден не согласиться с @МаркИз: в данном сообщении нет вопроса. Пожалуйста, задайте его, что получить ответ. Напоминаю, что вы можете сами отвечать на свой вопрос, но с помощью соответствующей формы ответа.

Comment: Я отредактировал вопрос. Его формулировка из сферы "мнений" перешла в сферу документированного знания.

Comment: В словаре под ред. профессора К.Д.Ушакова говорится  о том, что слово "кушать" "употребляется при вежливом или ласковом приглашении к еде". Никаких других помет или указаний по поводу "мещанского", просторечного, слащавого характера слова не содержится. Филологи в прошлом были более корректны  оценках... Вы в первый раз указали, что вопрос, мол,  закрыт, сославшись на исчерпывающие ответы "экспертов". Однако эти ответы неудовлетворительны по существу. Отсюда - появление моего вопроса. .

Comment: Борис, может эта статья будет вам полезна.   https://l.facebook.com/l.php?u=http%3A%2F%2Ffb.ru%2Farticle%2F239407%2Fkushat-ili-est-kak-pravilno-govorit-i-pisat&h=ATPfgsPEOEk4ur7JAtjWupNpXm5LcdKbDeUMEkECUHkA-QyyZcbWY-iiD2C2tFPlZLbXbCzEjJdp2e9b1s6jVwusCaTuL0bxdUdzWTbcN3wMvpTHU1bZLRdIF-AbvRriZZ28hMUWt0i73xBYr5XKJfERa0BfffanbHw0JFM6VKYnbe9wYMDtL5cxK8F4NJjpLTqsx4L04TSG_F3SoRxEf5fRplWA51t5F0C4RlFcDwlKzKa0U-8c4SxZYefXYfrvz2w2eArdLdA3hr5N9OXNrJM95QUg754qIE-GHDzVYDjg

Comment: Спасибо за подборку цитат! Использовала её в качестве аргумента в своей заметке: https://vk.com/id2613172?w=wall2613172_3924 . Животрепещущая тема)))

Answer (score 1):

**Значения слов меняются,  и в XXI веке говорят не так, как в XIX веке.**

Возьмем словарь:

**КУШАТЬ,** нсв. что. Есть, принимать пищу. Употр. в формулах вежливого приглашения к еде **(в нормативной речи в 1 л. не употр.).** К. подано! Пожалуйте к. Кушайте, пожалуйста! Кушай поскорее! (ребёнку). // Устар. Пить (чай, кофе, вино).

**В словаре указаны современные нормы употребления слова**, объяснения там не даются.  Для меня выражение  "я кушаю"  в речи взрослых людей совершенно неприемлемо и   очень  раздражает, когда так говорят другие. **Слащавость ли там, или лакейство, или отсутствие оных – это уже не сам вопрос, а история вопроса**. Здесь возможны разные мнения, можно что-то доказывать, приводить примеры. **Но говорить нужно согласно установленной норме.**

**Из личных впечатлений.** Когда-то мы снимали дачу у очень хорошо образованной еврейской семьи. Они были культурными людьми, жили в центре города, хорошо знали Москву, часто посещали концерты, театральные представления. Хозяйка, заезжая к нам, между делом  учила меня уму-разуму и в частности очень определенно высказалась по поводу глагола "кушать" – **категорически неправильно, ни в коем случае нельзя так говорить.**

Comment: Если Вы внимательно посмотрели приведенные мной примеры, то большая часть из них относится  к  XХ веку. Три из них взяты из произведений авторитетных современных писателей. Все эти словоупотребления относятся к нейтральным контекстам. Конечно, когда после революции миллионы носителей  образцового литературного языка эмигрировали, произошла смена элит и не всегда в сторону улучшения. Многие стремились говорить как пишут,  у части новой интеллигенции сложились предубеждения и понятия, которые заменили традицию, законы и дух языка. К их числу и относятся категорическое неприятие слова "кушать".

Comment: История этого вопроса, безусловно, интересна и поучительна, но это только история. Интересна и статистика употребления этих слов. Я не  исключаю, что это только столичная интеллигенция  (Москва и Петербург) категорически не желает "кушать".

Comment: Да и и сама культура застолья изменилась. Ну не сидим мы за столом по три часа, пробуя разные блюда. Некогда нам "кушать", ритм жизни  совсем другой.

Comment: Мамаев и Прилепин - из XXI  века. Вот еще пример:Будкин щёлкнул выключателем, снял наушники, встал, потянулся и, перешагнув через
Пуджика, пошёл на кухню.
– Когда, Надюша, обедать будем? – ласково спросил он.
– Здесь тебе столовая, что ли? Я на тебя не готовлю!
– Я же один живу… Никто меня не любит, никто не кормит…
– Меня это абсолютно не интересует! – отрезала Надя.
– Ну, я хоть полсантиметрика колбаски скушаю… (Алексей Иванов "Геолог глобус пропил").

Comment: А вот лауреат "Русского Букера" за 2016 год Петр Алешковский - "Крепость" – Голова кружится. – Она опустила глаза, положила голову ему на грудь. Так простояли какое то время, тихо и счастливо. Танечка очнулась первой. – Кушать будешь?
– Буду, голодный!

Comment: А это уже речь персонажей, которая их характеризует. Я уже говорила про статистику, может быть, все россияне, за исключением интеллигенции столичных городов, так говорят. (Это так же, как с глаголом звонЯт - звОнят).  Возможно, под давлением масс словари пойдут на уступку, и наше мужское население будет, как и дети, кушать, а не есть.

Comment: Предубеждение против этого слова (в том числе против использования его в речи мужчин)  сформировалось в XX веке. Современные писатели  следуют традиции русской  классической литературы, а не "давлению масс". "Массы", как раз, активно протестуют против этого слова, судя по недавней лавине  "лайков" в "Фейсбуке" в пользу мнения "эксперта", объявляющего употребление "кушать" недопустимым. Одной из причин развития этого предубеждения у масс, как мне кажется, является ассоциация с лакейским "кушать подано". После революции была популярна поговорка: "Лакеев нет с 17-го года".

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/66575/discussion-between---and-arina).

Comment: Да мне вроде бы и нечего больше добавить по теме, я не так хорошо ее знаю. Могу только выразить сомнение по поводу современных писателей, которые используют "кушать" в нейтральном стиле. Что касается речи персонажей, то она здесь не показатель.  Герои могут быть недостаточно образованны, или жить в глубинке, где все так говорят, или  (ещё вариант) использовать этот глагол в ироническом смысле.

Comment: Я бы мог попробовать предложить свой ответ на заданный мной вопрос, так как вижу, что удовлетворительного объяснения обозначенной мной проблемной ситуации пока не предложено, но, вижу, по реакции модераторов, на другие мои ответы ("средь шума людского"), подобная практика не приветствуется. Или я что-то не так пониманию в политике сайта?

Comment: Вы всегда можете сами ответить на свой вопрос, просто такая практика редко встречается. К тому же участники теряют изначальный  интерес к вопросу, когда уже высказались все, кто хотел, да и сама эта  тема не нова,  Поэтому никто не рассчитывает услышать  что-то принципиально отличное от уже сказанного.

Comment: Хорошо, понял, буду терпеливее.