# Правильно ли употреблено в предложении слово «кушать»?

Tags: грамотная-речь, значение-слов, стилистика

*В "Пушкине" (ресторане) уже **кушали** десерт: Ястыков -– миланез с апельсиновым кремом, Жанна – антреме из тропических фруктов. Новое явление парламентера было встречено дружным, заливистым смехом*  (Б. Акунин).

Мне кажется, что правильно. Это **нейтральный стиль или нет**?  Если слово употреблено верно, то как тогда нужно относиться **к рекомендациям филологов**?

**Комментарий**

Кушать или есть?

О, люди!  Вы всё еще спорите, а филологи для вас всё уже давно решили, например:

«Подведем итог: современная литературная норма не накладывает запрета на употребление слова кушать только женщинами по отношению к детям. Во всех остальных случаях следует употреблять **только стилистически нейтральное слово есть».**

Решить-то решили, но вот не слушается упрямый народ. **В Нацкорпусе много примеров с этим словом:** *кушал* – 388, *кушала* – 184, *кушали*  – 334   и даже *кушаю* –  82!

А может быть, наши филологи **«страшно далеки от народа»**?  Почему-то  никто из них не говорит о **семантических** оттенках этого слова, да и **стилистические** оттенки бывают разные, а не только всем известное  «кушают только дети».

И почему  в одной ситуации «кушать» действительно режет слух, а в другой кажется единственно правильным словом?

Comment: По-моему, он [тут](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MxY-9xB4a3s) очень хорошо разбирает этот вопрос и объясняет, что эти филологи в данном случае неправы.

Comment: Поиск по слову ["кушать"](https://rus.stackexchange.com/search?q=%D0%BA%D1%83%D1%88%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C) на этом самом ресурсе даёт не меньше дюжины обсуждений этой темы. На ваш последний вопрос "и почему..." - думаю, единственно возможный ответ: это определяется вашим индивидуальным чувством языка. И у других людей оно может отличаться. Где-то среди тех ссылок, помнится, отмечалось, что употребление, и, соответственно, восприятие слова "кушать" сильно разнится по регионам. И фраза, на которую москвич поморщится, будет совершенно нейтрально воспринята ростовчанином.

Comment: Здесь "кушать " , как мне кажется, в значении "пробовать, отведать" , поэтому звучит естественно.

Comment: Любопытна дискуссия с вашим же, Sharon, участием :)  октябрь 2017. https://rus.stackexchange.com/q/434564/181932

Comment: Я придаю этому слову значение "_есть с удовольствием и не спеша_", часто говорю так о _себе_ (причем не всегда с иронией), разумеется - о детях и кошках; легко могу себе представить себе употребление этого слова в обращении шеф-повара или официантки к взрослым клиентам: это естественно в атмосфере доброжелательности. В третьем лице мне это кажется уместным только в контексте поедания явных деликатесов, причем людьми, к которым относятся хорошо (о недругах не говорят, что они получали удовольствие от еды).

Comment: Да, я согласна. С моей точки зрения это и есть коннотация, стилистические оттенки. Еще могу добавить, что иногда "кушали" можно сказать и о недругах, но в ироническом плане. Ирония  часто используется для выражения негативного отношения.

Comment: Есть с удовольствием  — это «вкушать».

Answer (score 1):

**Ответ-комментарий**

Спасибо за комментарии.  С интересом прослушала запись (правда, только половину). **Вопросы остались.**

1. Я не думаю, что  эти слова нужно считать **полными синонимами** (по стилю и семантике), и это хорошо бы обозначить **в словаре**. Не хотелось бы полагаться только на **индивидуальное чувство** языка.
2. У нас есть **общелитературный нормированный язык**, региональные особенности в нем не учитываются, и это правильно. Должен быть какой-то образец  для русской речи.
3. Лично я говорю взрослым: «Есть будешь?», но никогда не скажу: «Кушать будешь?». А ребенку могу так сказать. Вероятно, это уже **влияние нормы, которое тоже исключать уже нельзя.**
   Когда-то давно учила меня этому весьма образованная  пожилая москвичка, проживающая в  самом центре города и вся погруженная в культурную среду (о ней я, оказывается, уже писала раньше). Это ведь тоже из жизни не выбросишь.
4. **Но это диалог,** а вот в тексте я считаю **нормой употребление обоих слов**,  но особую **коннотацию**  слова «кушать» всегда отмечаю. Поэтому мне хотелось бы получить ответ  относительно заданного предложения.
5. **О  дискуссии 2017 года**

За всё я в ответе… к тому же три с половиной года уже прошло, человек меняется. Да, больше во мне стало  индивидуализма и непослушания. Говорить по нормам? Ага, сейчас! Надо сначала  ваши словари проверить **на качество и соответствие**. Может, их надо  **править и дополнять,** очень уж там всё просто и категорично, а это плохо вписывается в нашу современную жизнь.

К тому же тогда я, кажется, не пользовалась **материалами из Нацкорпуса,** а ведь это **реальная практика** нашего письма и нашей речи. Может быть, составители словаря туда тоже не заглядывают.

Comment: *"За всё я в ответе…"* - в моем комментарии не было никакого укора или попытки что-то поставить вам в вину. А *"Говорить по нормам? Ага, сейчас!"* и вовсе подход, которого сам придерживаюсь. Вполне осознаю, что это не может привести ни к чему, кроме как "chat room", все-таки не удержусь от вопроса: *"Должен быть какой-то образец для русской речи."* - а можете как-то развить/обосновать? Вот я, честно говоря, не столь железобетонно уверен в этом. Хотя и не могу утверждать обратного.

Comment: Извините, вы меня неправильно поняли (это шутка, тогда у меня был другой профиль, я на это намекаю). А развить указанное утверждение я  могу только своими же мыслями. Наша страна такая большая, ну что с нами будет, если в каждом регионе будет свое наречие? Как нам тогда сохранить единый язык? Люди должны понимать оттенки местной речи, но нужно уметь  при необходимости переходить на речь общелитературную, нормированную.  Вот только нормы наши филологи должны отслеживать. Мы не можем говорить так же, как говорили наши классики в 19 веке. Язык меняется, и надо чувствовать и учитывать это.

Comment: *"Извините, вы меня неправильно поняли (это шутка, тогда у меня был другой профиль, я на это намекаю)."* - ничего страшного (и ничего необычного) в этом нет :) Людям, *при общении в таком формате* свойственно не понимать друг друга. Я отмечал это много раз, увы. *"Умение переходить на речь нормированную"* я вполне одобряю, но мы немного, как мне кажется, с вами расходимся в некоторых моментах. Я попробую сформулировать, но это будет, так сказать, с ходу. 1) Мне не кажется, что разговорному русскому грозит опасность стать "взаимно-непонятным" в ближайшее время (на нашем веку).

Comment: 2) Мне кажется, что где-то 90-95% населения абсолютно *плевать хотели* на филологов и орфо-какие-угодно-словари. То есть, усилия (и провалы) этих самых филологов в какой-то мере интересны лишь немногочисленной прослойке "любителей языка". И так было, в общем-то, всегда.   Поэтому, нет повода беспокоиться о том, что составители словарей не совсем идут в ногу с "живой народной речью". Я так думаю(с)Мимино. :)

Comment: Конечно, мы еще не скоро будем друг друга совсем не понимать, но тенденцию обозначим. Национальность, религия, язык - это такие болевые точки, которые ведут к разногласиям между людьми, с ними нужно обращаться осторожно. Что касается отношения к словарям, то я не уверена в процентах. Люди хотят, чтобы дети были образованными, иногда учатся вместе с ними. Вот губернатор Курской области  лишил чиновников премий за орфографические ошибки. Разные ситуации. Много пишут в Сетях (статьи там разные), а грамотности не хватает. Будет мотивация -  перестанут плевать на словари.