# "Я кушаю" или "Я ем"

Tags: грамотная-речь

Я родилась в Орле, с детства слово "кушать" не использовалось в речи - ни в детском саду, ни в школе, ни потом в университете. "Что вы там кушаете?" - впервые попалось 20 лет назад в переписке с русской женщиной из Казахстана. И знакомая из Екатеринбурга тоже "кушает", что мне режет слух. А в вашем городе "кушают" или "едят"?

Comment: Этот вопрос обсуждался на форуме уже несколько раэ. Вот самое недавнее обсуждение: https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/461426/%d0%9f%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d0%be-%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d1%83%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%82%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%be-%d0%b2-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b8-%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%be-%d0%ba%d1%83%d1%88%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c

Comment: Я читала обсуждения, мой вопрос не про стилистические нюансы, а про географию употребления слова. Для некоторых "я кушаю" абсолютно нормально, а другим режет слух.

Comment: О _географии_ можно было бы говорить в случае _диалектности_ слова "кушать" (словари этого не отмечают). На самом деле выбор зависит от _ситуации употребления_. Вот одна из версий (из Екатеринбурга, по случайному совпадению), где различие ситуаций толкуется по гендерно-возрастному признаку (что спорно, хотя такая версия и имеет право на существование). https://www.ekburg.ru/news/18/62240-kak-pravilno-est-ili-kushat/

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Кушать или есть?](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/40857/%d0%9a%d1%83%d1%88%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%82%d1%8c)

Comment: Я поняла про стилистику ;) Вот по теме из обсуждений: "Родилась и живу в Петербурге, с детства "кушать" не использовалось в речи - ни в детском саду, ни в школе, ни потом в университете... Значение слова известно и понятно, активно слышно по литературе, в основном все-таки не современной... И в реальной жизни "кушает" только подруга из Хабаровска... Что немножко режет слух... Других исследований не проводила, возможно, у кого-то иной опыт".

Comment: Частотность употребления слов в разных регионах не рассматривается сообществом Stack Exchange. Это епархия ститистиков от диалектологии.